# Cant retrieve Stripe checkout sessions (retrieve function not defined)

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate the new Stripe checkout sessions into my website. On the `NodeJS` backend, I am trying to get the price from the created `session`, so I would try to use the `checkout.sessions.retrieve` function. When I invoke it like this:

```
session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(cs_test_ABC*etc);
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve is not a function.

Can't really see where this `error` is coming from, as I am defining a `stripe` const at the beginning of my `NodeJS` file:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_AAAetc');
```

Has anyone encountered this before or knows possible steps to resolve this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the correct syntax to [retrieve the session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve?lang=node). I suspect that your version of stripe-node is not up to date. You need to be on at least version 6.28.0 to [retrieve Checkout sessions](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/releases?after=v6.29.0).

Comment: I feel like an idiot, but this was indeed the correct answer. Thanks!